# Apple Developer website outage - alternatives for submitting app

Tags: ios, provisioning

I'm about to leave on a trip overseas, and I'd like to submit my app update for review today as I really don't want to take my laptop with me (although it looks like I may have to). It's important that I release the app before I get back (mid-August) because of the back-to-school rush for education apps. The app is ready, but my distribution profile has expired. With the dev website down right now, what are my options for submitting the app?

Can I submit the app without the distribution profile? Is there some other way of exporting the Xcode build that I can "attach" the profile to later? Or do I just have to wait until they put up the website again and submit it from India?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the same boat as me. We're pretty much helpless until it goes live again. Can't submit without a profile, and can't create one.

Comment: And cannot download XCode or seeds, etc

Comment: Do you think contacting Apple would be worth anything? The issue is their responsibility, right?

Comment: I don't think they can physically DO anything. For all we know its impossible for anyone to generate certs right now because the systems are down. Tim Cook might not even be able to generate a provisioning profile right now.

Comment: Forgive me for thinking drastically (and with limited understanding), but apparently provisioning profiles are basically XML property lists, right? What needs to happen to generate one that we can't do locally? I have the entire provisioning profile except the expiration date has passed. What's stopping me from just changing the expiration date?

Comment: @architectpianist I recognize that the portal is back online, however I wanted to respond to your followup comment-question "What's stopping me from just changing the expiration date?". The Provisioning Profile is cryptographically signed by Apple to ensure the contents of the profile aren't...let's say creatively edited. If you could just simply edit the XML, then the 100 test device limit would be unenforceable; one could load in as many devices as needed or use the enterprise 'All Devices' setting. In short, You *could* edit the XML, but it would fail integrity checks and be denied by Xcode

Comment: Yes, I ended up discovering that. ;) Thanks for posting the additional information, though.

Answer (score 2):

If your distribution profile expired during the time of their outage, I am pretty sure based on their recent postings that they have extended those dates until they come back online, so if that is in fact the case you should be able to submit since iTunes connect is up and running.

Comment: Unfortunately it's been expired since May... I know, I should renew it, but I wasn't thinking about it until I needed to submit an update. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: As an update, some of apple's developer services are back on, please see: https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/